# How find the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{\ln{i^2}}{i^2}$?

Tags: limits, summation

find the

> $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln{2^2}}{2^2}+\dfrac{\ln{3^2}}{3^2}+\dfrac{\ln{4^2}}{4^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{\ln{n^2}}{n^2}\right)$$

My try:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln{2^2}}{2^2}+\dfrac{\ln{3^2}}{3^2}+\dfrac{\ln{4^2}}{4^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{\ln{n^2}}{n^2}\right)=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n^2}$$

and I know  solve this following

> $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n}=\ln{2}\left(C-\dfrac{\ln{2}}{2}\right)$$

where $C$ is Euler constant

Solution:note this following 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln{1}}{1}+\dfrac{\ln{2}}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n}-\dfrac{(\ln{n})^2}{2}\right)=l$$
we let
$$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^k\ln{k}}{k}$$

Comment: Are you sure it's $\ln (i^2)$ and not $(\ln i)^2$, right?

Comment: It's $\ln{(i^2)}$

Comment: There is some discussion at http://oeis.org/A073002, including an expression in terms of the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant (whatever that is).

Comment: Thank you,@GerryMyerson,But My answer How have this

Answer (score 6):

With the Riemann zeta function for $x>1$
$$\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$$ you get, taking the derivative term-wise 
$$\zeta'(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^x},$$ so your sum is (the first term vanishes)
$$2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n^2} = -2\zeta'(2) = 1.8750965\dots$$

Comment: Thank you,maybe have other close form?

Comment: Thank you,My book is answer it's $$\dfrac{1}{3}\pi^2(\gamma+\ln{(2\pi)}-12\ln{A})$$,where $A$ is  Glaisher-Kinkelin constant

Comment: Yes, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html formula (45), but IMO you missed a - sign.

Comment: How get this,Thank you