# How prove this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\ln{n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\ln^2{n}}{n}$

Tags: summation

show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln{n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln^2{n}}{n}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}\ln{2}+\ln^2{2}\left[\gamma-\dfrac{1}{3}\ln{2}\right]?$$

where the $\gamma$ is Eluer constant.

I remember this  sum is old:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln{n}}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}\ln{2}?$$
and think the general case
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln^p{n}}{n^q}=?$$

I have found this :[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535540/how-find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-i-2n-dfrac-lni2i2)  use idea: since
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^x}$$
then
$$f'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln{n}}{n^x}$$
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln^2{n}}{n^x}$$
$$f'''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\ln^3{n}}{n^x}$$
$$\cdots$$
But Now How find  this value $f'(1),f'(2),f''(1),f''(2),\cdots$?

maybe have some paper research it? Thank you

Comment: $$\zeta(x)=\sum_1^\infty\frac1{n^x}\qquad,\qquad \eta(x)=\sum_1^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^x}=\Big(1-2^{1-x}\Big)\cdot\zeta(x)$$ $$=>\qquad\sum_1^\infty(-1)^{n+p+1}\frac{\ln^pn}{n^x}=\eta^{(p)}(x)= \frac{d^p}{dx^p}\bigg[\Big(1-2^{1-x}\Big)\cdot\zeta(x)\bigg]$$ See [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) for more details.